# grunt-usemin with pattern is only replacing the first match

Tags: javascript, regex, grunt-usemin

I have the following in my gruntfile:

```
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css'],
    js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*'],
        patterns: {
            js: [
                [/css:["']styles\/?.*\/(.*\.css)['"]/g, 'revved css resolves']
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Which does what I want, given a javascript file with a reference to a revved css file, it replaces the occurrence. But only the first occurrence. I need this to work globally (hence the '/g' modifier. Any clues?

The input is a file that looks roughly like:

```
foo:{includes:{css:"styles/something.css"}},bar:{includes:{css:"styles/something.css"}}
```

What I end up with is (assuming 0123456 is the hash from rev):

```
foo:{includes:{css:"styles/0123456.something.css"}},bar:{includes:{css:"styles/something.css"}}
```

What I want is:

```
foo:{includes:{css:"styles/0123456.something.css"}},bar:{includes:{css:"styles/0123456.something.css"}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My regular expression was too greedy, I fixed this by replacing my pattern with `/css:"styles\/?[A-Za-z]*\/+([A-Za-z0-9]+\.css)"}/g` and now I am back in business.

Comment: Thank you for this inspiration, I forgot the `/g` modifier for my regExpr m(